# Rails 3 view sytax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Ruby 1.9.3-p194

Rails 3.0.3

I was having libcrypt errors today, and after hours of troubleshooting, I uninstalled rvm, ruby and gems.  I reinstalled everything, but now my application throws errors.  I made no changes to my code, but this worked fine before reinstallation:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (/home/username/apps/vits/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:19: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
if (current_user.admin == true, "Admin Menu", adminmenu_path...
/home/username/apps/vits/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:19: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...er.admin == true, "Admin Menu", adminmenu_path) );@output_bu....
/home/username/apps/vits/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:22: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end
');@output_buffer.append_if_string=  flash.each do |name, msg|
/home/username/apps/vits/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:22: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting '='
');@output_buffer.append_if_string=  flash.each do |name, msg|
/home/username/apps/vits/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:44: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end):
16:     <div id="header">
17:             <div class="wrap clear">                        
18:                 <% if current_user %>  
19:                     <%= link_to "Logout", logout_path %>  |  <%= link_to "Main Menu", usermenu_path %>  |  <%= link_to_if (current_user.admin == true, "Admin Menu", adminmenu_path) %>
20:                 <% end %>
21:             </div>
22: <%- flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
app/controllers/user_sessions_controller.rb:29:in `new'
```

Any ideas?  This is a bad RoR day for me.
Thanks in advance.  -Katie

Edited to add entire application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title><%= h(yield(:title) || "Vendor Invoice Tracking System (VITS)") %></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/scaffold.css" type="text/css" media="all" charset="utf-8" />
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'scaffold' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "tablesort.js" %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="siteholder">

    <div id="header">
            <div class="wrap clear">                        
                <% if current_user %>  
                    <%= link_to "Logout", logout_path %>  |  <%= link_to "Main Menu", usermenu_path %>  |  <%= link_to_if ((current_user.admin == true, "Admin Menu", adminmenu_path)) %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
<%- flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
<%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %></p>
<div class="clear"></div>
<%- end -%> 

        <% if current_user %>       
            <div id="content1">             
                <%= yield %>
            </div>

        <% else %>

            <div id="content">
                <div id="content1">
                </div>
                <%= yield %>
            </div>
        <% end %>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is this line:

```
<%= link_to_if (current_user.admin == true, "Admin Menu", adminmenu_path) %>
```

You don't need the `== true`, just:

```
<%= link_to_if (current_user.admin, "Admin Menu", adminmenu_path) %>
```

Will be fine. If for some reason you did need check equality, you'd need an extra pair of parentheses, e.g.:

```
<%= link_to_if ((current_user.role == "admin"), "Admin Menu", adminmenu_path) %>
```

Comment: current_user.admin is a boolean column, though.  I am not using a "role" table. does that make a difference?

Comment: when I do an rvm list, I get this message: `=* /home/username/.rvm/scripts/list: line 321: /home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/config: No such file or directory
ruby-1.9.3-p194 [  ]`  It's weird that I'm suddenly getting syntax errors, when I haven't touched my code.  This began after uninstalling and reinstalling rvm, ruby, rails

Comment: Can you post your whole application.html.erb?

Comment: Edited original post with full application.html.erb.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: OK you actually have too many brackets by the looks of it. Change `<%= link_to_if ((current_user.admin == true, "Admin Menu", adminmenu_path)) %>` to `<%= link_to_if (current_user.admin, "Admin Menu", adminmenu_path) %>` and let me know if it works/you get a different error

Comment: That's what I had originally, before trying your first suggestion.  Same error, I'm afraid.  :-/

Comment: The problem might be with `link_to_if`, try `<%= link_to("Admin Menu", adminmenu_path) if current_user.admin %>`